# Rounding numbers to a specific resolution

Tags: language-agnostic, resolution, rounding

I know many languages have the ability to round to a certain number of decimal places, such as with the Python:

```
>>> print round (123.123, 1)
    123.1
>>> print round (123.123, -1)
    120.0
```

But how do we round to an arbitrary resolution that is *not* a decimal multiple. For example, if I wanted to round a number to the nearest half or third so that:

```
123.123 rounded to nearest half is 123.0.
456.456 rounded to nearest half is 456.5.
789.789 rounded to nearest half is 790.0.

123.123 rounded to nearest third is 123.0.
456.456 rounded to nearest third is 456.333333333.
789.789 rounded to nearest third is 789.666666667.
```

Comment: This question has been asked plenty of times before.  Why would a user of your rep write a whole new question and supply your own answer for it?

Comment: @Alnitak, if you can find a dupe, _mark it so,_ that's what the flagging is for. I couldn't find one and, in response to a similar Python-specific one (rounding to quarters), I came up with a solution that was applicable to any resolution. My reasons: to increase the pool of good questions and because jeopardy-type questions and answers are considered fine, provided they're otherwise valid. And it's not like I'm hunting for rep, I've already hit the daily cap :-)

Comment: see 326476 and 7423023 - the questions aren't language agnostic but the answers generally are

Comment: That's fine but I usually find that people looking for a solution to somethin in C#, for example, will totally ignore VB or Python questions regardless of the answers. The close reason for questions is identical _question,_ not _similar question that may have relevant answers._ That's why I prefer language agnostic questions. Still, your votes are your own to wield as you see fit. If you disagree, vote it down or vote to close.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can round to an arbitrary resolution by simply scaling the number, which is multiplying the number by one divided by the resolution (or, easier, just dividing by the resolution).

Then you round it to the nearest integer, before scaling it back.

In Python (which is also a very good pseudo-code language), that would be:

```
def roundPartial (value, resolution):
    return round (value / resolution) * resolution

print "Rounding to halves"
print roundPartial (123.123, 0.5)
print roundPartial (456.456, 0.5)
print roundPartial (789.789, 0.5)

print "Rounding to thirds"
print roundPartial (123.123, 1.0/3)
print roundPartial (456.456, 1.0/3)
print roundPartial (789.789, 1.0/3)

print "Rounding to tens"
print roundPartial (123.123, 10)
print roundPartial (456.456, 10)
print roundPartial (789.789, 10)

print "Rounding to hundreds"
print roundPartial (123.123, 100)
print roundPartial (456.456, 100)
print roundPartial (789.789, 100)
```

In that above code, it's the `roundPartial` function which provides the functionality and it should be very easy to translate that into any procedural language with a `round` function.

The rest of it, basically a test harness, outputs:

```
Rounding to halves
123.0
456.5
790.0
Rounding to thirds
123.0
456.333333333
789.666666667
Rounding to tens
120.0
460.0
790.0
Rounding to hundreds
100.0
500.0
800.0
```