# Round float to the nearest 2/100

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I need to take a number like 0.405 and round it to 0.40 while also rounding 0.412 to 0.42.  Is there any built in function to do this?

Comment: Would `round(x/(0.02))*0.02` work?  (You'd have to check how you want boundary cases to be handled, because 2/100 isn't dyadic.)

Comment: seems to work, thanks, you should probably write it up if you want to points for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A general purpose solution, this allows rounding to an *arbitrary* resolution (well, other than zero of course, but a resolution of zero makes little sense <sup>(a)</sup>). For your case, you just need to provide `0.02` as the resolution, though other values are possible, as shown in the test cases.

```
# This is the function you want.

def roundPartial (value, resolution):
    return round (value / resolution) * resolution

# All these are just test cases, the first two being your own test data.

print "Rounding to fiftieths"
print roundPartial (0.405, 0.02)
print roundPartial (0.412, 0.02)

print "Rounding to quarters"
print roundPartial (1.38, 0.25)
print roundPartial (1.12, 0.25)
print roundPartial (9.24, 0.25)
print roundPartial (7.76, 0.25)

print "Rounding to hundreds"
print roundPartial (987654321, 100)
```

This outputs:

```
Rounding to fiftieths
0.4
0.42
Rounding to quarters
1.5
1.0
9.25
7.75
Rounding to hundreds
987654300.0
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> If you have the particular personality disorder that *requires* you to handle this possibility, just be aware that you're after the closest number that is a multiple of your desired resolution. Since the closest number to `N` (for *any* `N`) that is a multiple of 0 is always 0, you could modify the function as follows:

```
def roundPartial (value, resolution):
    if resolution == 0:
        return 0
    return round (value / resolution) * resolution
```

Alternatively, you could simply promise yourself not to pass zero as a resolution :-)

Comment: I think a better way to handle a resolution of zero would just be to return the input. If you think of it in the limit as the resolution tends to zero, the output tends to the input.

Comment: Too bad you haven't pointed the OP to your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8118982/12892) and [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8119014/12892).

Answer (score 0):

A small fix to the earlier solution:

```
def roundPartial (value, resolution):
    return round (float(value) / resolution) * resolution
```

Earlier

```
roundPartial(19, 10) = 10.0
```

With fix

```
roundPartial(19, 10) = 20.0
```