# Round to nearest X

Tags: javascript

There is probably a simple answer to this question but I can't seem to find it. I have a number (dollar amount) such as 0.34, I would like to round this to the nearest X, meaning if X is 0.15 I want it to round to 0.15, 0.3, 0.45, 0.6, 0.75 or 0.9. This is just an example I don't want those exact numbers, I want to be able to make X anything between 0.01 and 0.5 and any number can be rounded to that increment.

This question here rounds to the nearest 0.25 which is kind of what I want buy I want a generic function that rounds any numbers decimal portion to any set fraction.

[round to nearest .25 javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553704/round-to-nearest-25-javascript)

```
Number.prototype.round2dec = function(x){
  return /* Do something to "this" to round to nearest x */;
};
```

Comment: Would you be OK if it fixes it to 2 decimal places?

Comment: Um, the answer was in the question you linked to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27861660/902497

Comment: No not just to .25, but to any fraction, so that question doesn't help

Comment: @DustinPoissant: Just read [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27861660/1048572) to it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645406/round-float-to-the-nearest-2-100/17645513#17645513 - it's Python but the math is identical.

Comment: Both those formulas only work when the increment evenly divides `1`.  That doesn't work for `0.15`.

Comment: What is your expected answer if the amount is `1.10`? Do you want `1.05` (which is a multiple of `0.15`) or `1.15` (just rounding the fractional part)?

Comment: I guess I did not think of that, I am building a widget which allows you to increment/decrement a counter by hitting buttons (will incrament by X when the `+` button is press) and that part is easy. But I want user to be able to enter the number manually and then it rounds it to the nearest X. So I guess the first one `1.05` makes more sense, which this does I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Number.prototype.round2dec = function(x){
  return (Math.round(this * (1/x)) / (1/x));
};
```

From the example given, 4 = `1/(0.25)`, so I expanded that pattern to any X.

EDIT - from looking through the answers, I just realized you do have an answer there, but not expanding the `prototype` - [round to nearest .25 javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553704/round-to-nearest-25-javascript/27861660#answer-27861660).

Comment: Or rather `return Math.round(this / x) * x;`

Comment: Agreed with @Bergi, your function returns a String, don't need that toFixed.

Comment: This is perfect after you removed the .toFixed()

Comment: It wont let me accept this answer yet apparently I have to wait a certain amount of time but Ill mark this as the correct answer

Comment: What would `x` be if you want to round to the nearest `0.15`?

Comment: Yes, it works.  If you want to round `something` to the nearest 0.15, you'd do `something.round2dec(0.15)`.

Comment: @Barmar: It doesn't need to divide 1 evenly. We're just rounding to the nearest *multiple of* `x`. Of course, floating point inaccuracies do hit hard.

Comment: It's not clear what he wants to do for a number like `1.1`. The nearest multiple of `.15` is `1.05`, but he might want `1.15`.

Comment: Rounding means that something at 0.5 will round up to 1 (so then 1.1 would be 1.15, since it's in the middle and rounds up).

Comment: I answered the question of `1.05` vs `1.15` in the comments of the question. I am looking for `1.05`. I guess I should have continued the example and not assumed everyone would know what I meant by "ect", it is a little confusing but this is correct. Read my other comment above for a better explaination of how I am using it and why `1.05` is correct

Comment: If you do want `1.15` all you have to do is separate out the whole number from the decimal by using `var w = Math.floor(this)` to get the whole and `var d = this - w` to get the decimal then call this method on the decimal and recombine to get `1.15`.